# Why do I have to bind this function argument?

Tags: javascript

```
// example A (works)
foo(function() {
    myObj.save();
});

// example B (doesn't work)
foo(myObj.save);

// example C (works)
foo(myObj.save.bind(myObj));
```

Why is the `this` reference correct when `myObj.save` is called in `example A`, but not in `example B`?

I can force `this` to be correct by using `bind`, but what is happening in `example A` that is different from `example B`?

I don't understand why `this` would be different.

Comment: Because current method for object can change. This pattern is called signal pattern. You giving current implementation of function but in other place it can be change by other method or function. This method / function can't be use also by other object so making it contextful create new function (with owner) object. And this why you need to bind it. For performance reason this is made only on demand.

Answer (score 2):

Functions only have a context, `this`, when invoked.

When you call `x.y()`, the `this` context inside `y` is `x`.

When you write `x.y`, you're referencing just the function `y`, you're not invoking it and there is no context. When you pass that function elsewhere, such as `z = x.y`, the context is not passed with it.

You're doing that in your second example. You're passing the function *without context* into `foo`, where there is no possible way for `foo` to know what the context should be. When it's invoked by `foo`, it's going to be invoked a simple `save()` call, and when this happens the `this` context will be `window` (or `null` in strict mode).

Answer (score 1):

This is because `this` refers to the object on which a method was called. When you set the method of a function to a variable, or pass it in as an argument, it is no longer associated with the object it was a method of.

Multiple objects can share the same function, `this` is a way of dynamically reusing that function to manipulate the object instance it is a method of.

The [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method was added later to address use cases such as these.